# Use Bootstrap 3 with IE 8. But it does not work. I tried using respond/modernizr/html5shiv JS but it does not correct it. any solution?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, responsive-design, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcd
n.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">

<script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="modernizr.custom.95176.js"></script>
```

DIVs with Grid system:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="middlediv">
        <div class="middledivimg">
        <img src="img/mid1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="middledivtxt">
            <h3>Travel</h3>
            <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
            lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

These JS suppose to correct the bootstrap grid system. But it does not do the trick. Lot of people have tried to find a solution. But it seems impossible.
Any solution yet ?

Comment: have you checked here? [**Browser and device support**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)

Comment: yeh i did but it does not do the trick. it says  it does not support some functions. But I need  a way to find media queries to work ..

Answer (score 0):

No where have you included jQuery.

For IE8 you need to include the JQuery 1.x series for bootstrap to work.

Comment: Yes I have added it .. sorry its not displaying in the question. 1.1 jquery still not working ...  It initiates bootstrap but it shows mobile version of the site even for the desktop version ... that's main issue .. it reads the Bootstrap for mobile first for any width(larger desktop/desktop) ...